# Cannot call non W3C standard command while in W3C mode

Tags: typescript, selenium, protractor, w3c

yesterday I ran into this error while running my code in Jenkins using Linux.

this is how my conf.ts looks like :

```
framework: 'jasmine',
//  directConnect: true,
capabilities: {
, 
browserName: 'chrome', 
platform: 'ANY',

**chromeOptions: { 'args': ['disable-infobars', 'start-maximized'], w3c: false },**
```

the w3c is false.

I'm using typescript over selenium and protractor,

The google chrome version is the latest 80.0.3987.106.

**I just want to emphasize that if I run the code locally then it works perfectly fine (using windows 10)
but on remote using Linux I get the error above.**

**Everything worked perfectly up until yesterday but I didn't change anything related to it.**

Many thanks.

Comment: the fix to apply chromeOptions{"w3c": false} worked for chrome v75 and associated chromedriver, but I am now experiencing this again with v80.0.3987.106 and the chromeOptions fix does not help

Comment: @Shai @ MikeW- Same issue when I run my protractor tests in docker. Did you find any solution for this ?